# Receiving the LINQ expression x could not be translated error when using a properly loaded list object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following `List` object which is properly loaded with valid values from the database:

```
  List<AssessmentItem> assessmentItems = 
      _context.AssessmentItems
              .Include(ai => ai.Assessment).ThenInclude(assess => assess.Evaluator)
              .Where(ai => ai.IsActive &&
                           ai.Assessment.SubmissionId == submissionId &&
                           ai.Assessment.RubricId == rubricId)
              .ToList();
```

Then I need to use this `assessmentItems` list object inside another LINQ statement. I provide the partial code below where `assessmentItems` is used.

```
   ....
   Description = ri.Description,
   Abbreviation = ri.Abbreviation,
   RubricId = ri.RubricId,
   RubricItemCategoryId = ri.RubricItemCategoryId,
   CurrentScores = assessmentItems
                         .Where(aitem => aitem.RubricItemId == ri.Id)
                         .Select(aitem => new AssessmentItemDTO
                         {
                             Id = aitem.Id,
                             EvaluatorName = aitem.Assessment.Evaluator.FirstName + " " + aitem.Assessment.Evaluator.LastName,
                             EvaluatorId = aitem.Assessment.EvaluatorId,
                             CurrentScore = aitem.CurrentScore
                         }).ToList(),
```

For some reason I receive the following error:

> The LINQ expression `'aitem'` could not be translated. Either rewrite
> the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
> evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

I checked other related posts in SO however I could not find a solution for my case. I am using the latest version of EF Core. Any help?

Comment: How do you expect this to be translated and executed as SQL? Send your list (how?) to the database in order to somehow return it back (after filtering)? If you want to use it in another query, remove `ToList()` and use it as subquery (`IQueryable<>` variable).

Comment: try change to 
.Where(witem => aitem.RubricItemId == ri.Id)